# Thorntail - Datasource configuration - not connecting

Tags: datasource, thorntail

I am running Thorntail using Fat JAR Builder.
I am trying to get Datasource sample to work.

I tested using SQLClient both mySQL/Oracle connections and they work fine.
But I am unable to get Datasource using Thorntail application.
In both cases, the connection is refused.

Here is the Yaml configuration.

```
ORACLE :

swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      ExampleDS:
        driver-name: oracle
        connection-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE
        user-name: USER
        password: PWD
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: true
        background-validation: false
        stale-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter
```

Here is relevant logs-

```
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370)
    ... 16 more
```

Same is the case with  MYSQL Connection

Yaml

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    jdbc-drivers:
      com.mysql:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        xa-datasource-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
        driver-module-name: com.mysql
    data-sources:
      ExampleDS:
        driver-name: com.mysql
        connection-url: jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/dbname
        user-name: user 
        password: pwd
```

Relevant Logs

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
```

Comment: Please proof read your questions.  If the format is not good, edit it and fix the question.  Ex. Yaml sections can be set as code using the `{}` icon on top of the editor.  See [ask].

Comment: @Nic3500 - Thankyou for formatting.

Comment: Verify if you can reach and connect to those databases from the machine that you're running Thorntail on. It looks like an issue trying to make the connection